# RaspberryPi camera stream processing with Python 2.7

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, image-processing, raspberry-pi

I found following code [here](https://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/recipes2.html) for catching a video stream from the RaspberryPi camera.

Now I want to process the video stream (e.g. finding BLOB or display the video).

For this purpose I need to catch the content of the video as array, e.g. with the name `frame` in this example:

```
cv2.imshow('stream', frame)
```

I tried it by converting it into an array like

```
frame = self.stream.array
```

but somewhat I am not getting it to work.

The output tells me that I cannot create an array with the stream:

```
File "Raspberry.py", line 35, in run
    frame = self.stream.array   #creating an array for the stream
AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'array'
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

Code:

```
import io
import time
import threading
import picamera

# Create a pool of image processors
done = False
lock = threading.Lock()
pool = []

class ImageProcessor(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ImageProcessor, self).__init__()
        self.stream = io.BytesIO()
        self.event = threading.Event()
        self.terminated = False
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        # This method runs in a separate thread
        global done
        while not self.terminated:
            # Wait for an image to be written to the stream
            if self.event.wait(1):
                try:
                    self.stream.seek(0)

                    frame = self.stream.array   #creating an array for the stream                   

                    cv2.imshow('stream', frame) #should show the livestream



                    # Read the image and do some processing on it
                    #Image.open(self.stream)
                    #...
                    #...
                    # Set done to True if you want the script to terminate
                    # at some point
                    #done=True
                finally:
                    # Reset the stream and event
                    self.stream.seek(0)
                    self.stream.truncate()
                    self.event.clear()
                    # Return ourselves to the pool
                    with lock:
                        pool.append(self)

def streams():
    while not done:
        with lock:
            if pool:
                processor = pool.pop()
            else:
                processor = None
        if processor:
            yield processor.stream
            processor.event.set()
        else:
            # When the pool is starved, wait a while for it to refill
            time.sleep(0.1)

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    pool = [ImageProcessor() for i in range(4)]
    camera.resolution = (640, 480)
    camera.framerate = 30
    camera.start_preview()
    time.sleep(2)
    camera.capture_sequence(streams(), use_video_port=True)

# Shut down the processors in an orderly fashion
while pool:
    with lock:
        processor = pool.pop()
    processor.terminated = True
    processor.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

The base picamera package doesn't provide the array capability to prevent a lengthy numpy compile on the Raspberry Pi if you don't really need it.

To install with numpy array support, try:

```
pip install --user "picamera[array]"
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea!
However I already installed that one. Is there anything I should change or add in my code then?